# How to format currency values in valueBox shinydashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, currency, dashboard

I'm trying to write a dashboard with shinydashboard in R to display some values using renderValueBox and valueBoxOutput. These values are not hardcoded but are being scraped from another source daily.
These values are currency numbers and should be reporting like $XXX,XXX.XX but instead I see XXXXXX.XX. Is there a way, like a wrapper, to easily format those values? Otherwise I've thought of brute forcing some regex on it with gsub...but ew. Please and thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discovered the function `prettyNum()`: this function is amazing for simple conversion to comma separated numerics.

```
> prettyNum(56789, big.mark = ",")
> 56,789
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the `{scales}` package and the `dollar_format()` function.
This function is a **labelling** function factory, in the sense that it creates other functions.

I usually need to output numbers in euros, so I defined the following function:

```
euro_format <- scales::dollar_format(
  prefix = "\u20ac", # the euro symbol
  suffix = "",
  big.mark = ",",
  decimal.mark = ".",
  accuracy = 1
)

>euro_format(20842)
[1] "€20,842"
```